# Add Identifier (id) to Web Page Text Field

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

We know that  we can use the `id` attribute in HTML tags to provide each HTML tag an identifier for use.

Now, I am using Angular JS ng-grid in a `controller` JS file to create web page input fields (code snippet is shown below).  I already have `columnDefs` defining name/field pairs.  (The code works.)

How do I assign an `id` to each of those input fields?

Code snippet:

```
var injectParams = ['$scope', '$log', '$location', 'caseService', 'ngDialog'];


var DraftCasesController = function ($scope, $log, $location, caseService, ngDialog) {

    //  initial setting - true upon selecting case from Master (table)
    $scope.showDraftCaseDetail = false;
            $scope.$scope = $scope;             
            $scope.gridOptions = {
                pagingPageSizes: [5, 10, 10],
                pagingPageSize: 5,                    
                enableSorting: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                enableSelectionBatchEvent: false,
                enableRowSelection: true,
                enableSelectAll: false,
                enableRowHeaderSelection:false,
                columnDefs: [
                    {name:'Case Identifier', field: 'number'},
                    {name:'Violator', field: 'violator', allowCellFocus : false },
                    {name:'Case Type', field: 'caseTypeDescription'},
                    {name:'Violation Type', field: 'violationType'},
                    {name:'Date Created',field: 'caseCreationDate'},
                    {name:'Delete?',field: 'caseId', enableFiltering:false,enableCellEdit: false,cellTemplate: '<button id="deleteBtn" type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="getExternalScopes().deleteCase(row)" ></button> '}
            ],
                onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                        //$scope.grid1Api = gridApi;
                        gridApi.selection.on.rowSelectionChanged($scope,function(row){

                         if(row.isSelected)
                         {
                         scope.getDraftCaseData(row.entity.caseId);                             
                            $scope.showDraftCaseDetail = true;
                         }
                        });
                }
            };
```

Comment: What value would you like the `id` to be?

Answer (score 0):

You can read the value of the property in the `columnDefs` using this:

```
{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}
```

So, your button template can be changed to this in order to set the `id`:

```
'<button id="{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}" type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="getExternalScopes().deleteCase(row)" ></button>'
```

This is assuming that you want to set `id` to the `caseId` value.

You can find more examples of this in the [documentation for cell template](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Templating).